# Replicate columns - Excel / OpenTBS

Tags: php, xlsx, opentbs

is there any way to replicate columns in excel, using openTBS, instead of replicate cells..

I tried to post some images to show u my problem, but some prevention mechanism didnt let me.

im trying to replicate a column for each value in [base_sub2.module;block=c] but this just create new cells instead of a entire column..

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry for my english.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no possible for current version of OpenTBS to replicate full columns in an XLSX worksheet instead of a simples cells.

It is possible for rows, but no for columns.
This is because the XML data of a XLSX worksheet is organized as rows and cells. Columns are landmarks but have not actual entities.

The solution for expending columns is to use several blocks like in the XLSX example given in package.